# Convert a given unix time string (EST) to local server time (CST) and evaluate difference between unix time and current time

Tags: javascript, epoch

I have been struggling with comparing between two date/times using javascript. I'm trying to evaluate the difference between a unix time string that is provided (presumably EST) and the current time in javascript format (any timezone the server is running in) and get the difference in hours/minutes/milliseconds.

I believe there are three approaches that I can try / have tried:

1. Convert the current server's javascript time in the given timezone to unix time, then subtract the provided unix time from it
2. Convert the provided unix time to javascript format based on the server's timezone and then subtract it from the server's current time
3. Convert both times to UTC or GMT and do math on it

I have scoured StackOverflow and tried many different approaches for  these approaches and have not been able to get an accurate value.

For example, if the provided unix time is `1599206400000`, and the current server's javascript time is `Fri Sep 04 2020 16:47:26 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)`, how do I get the difference in milliseconds between the two?

I apologize that there is no code example. The reason for this is I have tried so many different  revisions of code without success, what I have in front of me doesn't reflect all of those efforts any longer.

Please help if you can and thank you in advance! I've been struggling with this problem for two days straight!

Comment: Ideally you should be able to get the GMT time for both the user and the server, before doing any math.

Comment: @Taplar I've tried a few different permutations of that (but for UTC) with the `setUTCDate()` method without success... Note this is server-side only. The Unix Epoch string is coming from an API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **Server:** Recommend to use **UTC (ISO-8601 format)**. It is the standard serialization format.
- **Client:** Client can process times locally and send UTC equiv. using `toISOString` to Server.

If you are looking for plain JS code, `getTime()` - this returns Unix time and is timezone-free.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime

Lets take your example:

```js
const timeA = 1599206400000;  // already Unix time
const timeB = new Date(2020, 08, 04, 16, 47, 26, 531).getTime(); // getTime()
console.log(timeA, timeB, difference(timeB - timeA));
```

**Output:**

```
1599206400000 1599218246531 {hour: 3, min: 17, seconds: 26, milliseconds: 531}
```

Definition of `difference` function:

```
const difference = (millis) => {
    const parts = [(millis / 3600000) % 60, (millis / 60000) % 60, (millis / 1000) % 60, millis % 1000];
    const [hour, min, seconds, milliseconds] = parts.map((v) => parseInt(v));
    return { hour, min, seconds, milliseconds };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**I. You could use the [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) to solve this problem:**

```js
timestampInMilliseconds = 1599206400000;
currentTimestampInMilliseconds = parseInt(moment.utc().format('x'));
currentTimestampInMilliseconds - timestampInMilliseconds;
// Example return value 94092301
```

1. To get the current time in `UTC` use: `moment.utc()`
2. To get the timestamp from a momentJS date formatted in milliseconds use: `format('x')`
3. You also need to cast it to `int` (with help of `parseInt` function) directly cause the output of `format` function is of type `string`

**II. The plain JS solution is even simpler:**

```js
timestampInMilliseconds = 1599206400000;
currentTimestampInMilliseconds = (new Date).getTime();
currentTimestampInMilliseconds - timestampInMilliseconds;
// Example return value 94092301
```

You can freely use `getTime()` in this case, cause the official docs say: [getTime() always uses UTC for time representation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime)

Comment: Thanks - I did attempt using moment.js but ended up just as confused and struggled with it all the same.. If you have an example of how to use it for this purpose I could move forward.. There is no documentation that I could find about converting Unix Epochs using moment.js

Comment: @Dshiz please check the answer. I've updated it with an example.

Comment: Does the timestamp length change this? The timestamp I get back from the API I'm using is this long `1599163201067`. I think it's because it contains milliseconds.

Comment: It does appear to change the results... this is why I was struggling with momentjs... Using the longer timestamp, the value is negative: `-1597563942522856`

Comment: @Dshiz I've adopted the answer for milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

```js
// timestamp
var d = new Date()
d.setHours(4) // 4am
d.setMinutes(00) //00 minutes

var unixTimeStamp = Math.floor(d.getTime() / 1000); // converts to unix time

console.log(unixTimeStamp)

var apicurrentTime
var timeStamp


var differenceintime = apicurrentTime - timeStamp
```